# waiting time for D/M/1-LCFS queue

Tags: probability-distributions, queueing-theory

The stationary distribution of waiting time for a D/M/1 queue is well known if the first-come first-serve (FCFS) discipline is adopted.

If, however, the last-come first-serve (LCFS) discipline is adopted, then no theoretical results appear in the literature (as far as I can see).

This would be a surprising gap in the literature, especially since a relevant computer simulation is so easy to write.

Am I missing something in my literature search?  Thoughts or suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Wishart (1960) answered my question, although I didn't know this fact until a fairly short time ago.

I've gathered relevant information about the D/M/1 queue in

https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.08545

for others to see.  Section 2 contains formulas concerning the LCFS policy, also called LIFO (last-in-first-out).  Figure 1 exhibits a plot of the probability density function for the waiting time.  Two other preprints of mine discuss the M/D/1 queue.